# Laravel: Place for controller echo in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

First Laravel Project.

How to define a place in the view for the echo in controller?

I have sometimes "echoes" in my controller. For example if a MySQL statement has null output it echoes "MySQL select is empty" or after succesfull fileupload: "File upload is succesfull".

Right now it appears outside of the body tag at the top left corner of the screen. I want to place it inside the main section or a modall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to redirect back with errors

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['mysql' => 'MySQL select is empty']);
```

And then get it in the view (modal)

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

You can watch this laracast for more about errors: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/12

Comment: Thank you, this is what I searched. I can accept your answer in 7 minutes.